# Eliminacion de caracter al Exportar Gridview a TXT, delimitados por comillas simples C#

Tags: c#, exportar

he estado trabajo en exportar datos a txt para lo cual tengo una instruccion que me permite exportar los datos de una gridview a un archivo .txt

```
StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewDefault.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell redatos in row.Cells)
                {
                    stringWrite.Write(redatos.Text + ",");
                }
                stringWrite.WriteLine(""); 
            }
```

hasta ahi todo funciona perfecto, se escriben los datos y los delimita por coma ','.

los datos me los presenta de la siguiente manera en el .txt

```
02,CC,1140417534,6001044,4709000,30/09/2020,BETA BETA BETA,
```

Requiero eliminar la ultima comilla y mostrar la informacion de esta forma:

```
 02,CC,1140417534,6001044,4709000,30/09/2020,BETA BETA BETA
```

para lo cual he intentado lo siguiente:

```
StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewDefault.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell redatos in row.Cells)
                {
                    stringWrite.Write(redatos.Text + ",");
                    redatos.Text.Substring(0, redatos.Text.Length - 1);
                }
                stringWrite.WriteLine(""); 
            }
```

lo anterior no me resulta, y no he logrado el asunto que puedo modificar

Comment: saca afuer del foreach el substring y listo...

Comment: De que tipo es "GridViewDefault"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma muy simple de logarlo es usando el `string.Join()` para unir los items de la linea separandolos por la `,`

```
StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewDefault.Rows)
{
    var items = new List<string>();
    foreach (TableCell redatos in row.Cells)
    {
        items.Add(redatos.Text);
    }
    
    string linea = string.Join(",", items);
    stringWrite.WriteLine(linea); 
}
```

de esta forma no necesitas poner logica para quitar ese ultimo caracter

Comment: Hola @Leandro, Gracias por tu apoyo, queria comentar que al incluir la siguiente linea:  `items.Add(redatos.Text);`, no me reconoce la propiedad .Text, Arroja: Object no contiene una definicion de text

Comment: quizas entonces necesite que la definas como `TableCell`, quizas hice mal en cambirlo a `var` en el foreach, ponlo como estaba antes `foreach (TableCell redatos in row.Cells)`

Comment: perfecto leandro, Eso era

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tiene es que evitar que la coma se le agregue cuando es la ultima columna de la celda, evaluando dentro del for que recorre las celdas si ya la celda es o no la ultima

Mas o menos asi:

```
StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewDefault)
{
    var cntCells = row.Cells.Count; //Obtiene la cantidad de celdas en la fila
    var iCell = 0; //Variable que controla en que celda de la fila va
    foreach (TableCell redatos in row.Cells)
    {
        iCell ++; //Incrementa la variable decontrol
        if (iCell < cntCells)
        {
            //Aun no es la ultima celda de la fila
            stringWrite.Write(redatos.Text + ",");
        }
        else {
            //Es la ultima celda de la fila. No se debe agregar la coma
            stringWrite.Write(redatos.Text);
        }
        redatos.Text.Substring(0, redatos.Text.Length - 1);
    }
    stringWrite.WriteLine("");
}
```